# jar for spring-test-mvc

Tags: maven, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to get a jar for Spring-test mvc.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This dependency can´t be resolved. Where can I get the jar?

Thanks

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.2.RELEASE

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande This is not what I am looking for I think

Comment: Consider moving to Spring 3.2 - https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc

Answer (score 3):

As stated in their [Github repository](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc), you have to define the following repository in your `pom.xml` / `settings.xml`:

http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/

The dependency is here:

http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone/org/springframework/spring-test-mvc/1.0.0.M1/

Note that there is a **1.0.0.M2** release.

Comment: Is there anything that is not milestones?

Answer (score 0):

Since 4.0.0.M1 it is included in spring-test (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2015)
See the sample usage at https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-test-blog (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2592)